# create combination dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe similar to following:

```
q  =sc.parallelize([Row(items=[1]), Row(items=[2]), Row(items=[2, 1]), Row(items=[5]), Row(items=[5, 2]), Row(items=[5, 2, 1]), Row(items=[5, 1]), Row(items=[3]), Row(items=[3, 5]), Row(items=[3, 5, 2]), Row(items=[3, 5, 2, 1]), Row(items=[3, 5, 1]), Row(items=[3, 2]), Row(items=[3, 2, 1]), Row(items=[3, 1])])
```

I need to create a new dataframe which contains all combination of items:

```
+------------+--------------+
|       left | right
+------------+---------------
|         [1]|[2]
|         [1]|[2, 1]
|         [1]|[5]
|         [1]|[5,2]
|         [1]|[5,2,1]
|         [1]|[5,1]
|         [1]|[3]
|         [1]|[3,5]
|         [1]|[3, 5, 2]
|         [1]|[3, 5, 2, 1]
|         [1]|[3,5,1]
|         [1]|[3,2]
|         [1]|[3,2,1]
|         [1]|[3, 1]|
|         [2]|[1]
|         [2]|[2,1]
...
+------------+
```

I need to create a dataframe looks like above

Answer (score 0):

Try the `crossJoin`method:

```
q.crossJoin(q)
```

That should do the trick.